# Reading data from _transaction_state topic in Kafka 0.11.0.1

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, messagebroker, string-decoding

I want to read meta data for transaction (which is supported in Kafka 0.11.0.1) so that I can figure out that whether the transaction for a particular transactional ID has been committed or not. Currently I am getting the key and value from _transactional_state topic but it is in some encoded format.
Below are some same key/value I received when I polled __transaction_state topic:
key =    10000000mmm, value =         �   �`����`+'���������)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look to source code of `TransactionLogMessageParser` class inside `kafka/tools/DumpLogSegments.scala` file as an example.  It uses `readTxnRecordValue` function from `TransactionLog` class.  The first argument for this function could be retrieved via `readTxnRecordKey` function of the same class.

Comment: Hey @alex, thanks for help. I got the required code will try to integrate it with my module.

Comment: You can import and use `kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionLog.readTxnRecordValue` directly by depending on the `org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11` artifact.

Answer (score 5):

just like what has been done in [Kafka how to read from __consumer_offsets topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925866/kafka-how-to-read-from-consumer-offsets-topic)

`echo "exclude.internal.topics=false" > consumer.config`

`kafka-console-consumer --consumer.config consumer.config --formatter "kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionLog\$TransactionLogMessageFormatter" --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic __transaction_state --from-beginning`