# How to monitor TRANSACTIONAL_ID in use by kafka clients?

Tags: security, apache-kafka, monitoring

This is probably more about producers. There is a need to define appropriate ACL for each resource in use by clients if allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=false is about to be set, which should be desired state anyway, so, how can one monitor this to find out what is actually needed, without developer's help?

Answer (score 0):

I guess currently there is no better answer to that question than this:

[Reading data from _transaction_state topic in Kafka 0.11.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670477/reading-data-from-transaction-state-topic-in-kafka-0-11-0-1)

To improve it a bit, let us post the link to the relevant class, namely this:

https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/kafka/coordinator/transaction/TransactionLog.scala

If I compare my result of proposed kafka-console-consumer command with TransactionLogMessageFormatter applied to it, to the implementation presented there in readTxnRecordValue function, I see that I miss some TransactionMetadata, my record looks something like this:

txn_id::TransactionMetadata(transactionalId=txn_id, producerId=440243, producerEpoch=14094, txnTimeoutMs=600000, state=Empty, pendingState=None, topicPartitions=Set(), txnStartTimestamp=-1, txnLastUpdateTimestamp=1613483758593)

So, no lastProducerId and lastProducerEpoch, probably due to the older version that I am running (kafka_2.13-2.6.0)?