# consumer reading __consumer_offsets delivers unreadable message

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to consume from the __consumer_offsets topic as it seemed this may be the easiest way to retrieve kafka metrics about consumers like message lag etc. The ideal way is accessing it from jmx but wanted to try this first and the messages that come back seem to be encrypted or in unreadable form. Tried adding stringDeserializer property as well. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to correct this? Again the reference to this being a duplicate of

[duplicate consumer_offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925866/kafka-how-to-read-from-consumer-offsets-topic)

is not helpful as it does not reference my issue which is to read message as a string in java. Updated the code as well to try a consumerRecord using kafka.client consumer.

```
consumerProps.put("exclude.internal.topics",  false);
consumerProps.put("group.id" , groupId);
consumerProps.put("zookeeper.connect", zooKeeper);


consumerProps.put("key.deserializer",
  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");  
consumerProps.put("value.deserializer",
  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

ConsumerConfig consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig(consumerProps);
ConsumerConnector consumer = 
kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(
       consumerConfig);

Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(1));
Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = 
   consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);

for (KafkaStream stream : streams) {

    ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();

    //errorReporting("...CONSUMER-KAFKA CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL!");

    while (it.hasNext()) {
         try {

             String mesg = new String(it.next().message());
             System.out.println( mesg);
```

code changes:

```
try {       
    // errorReporting("CONSUMER-KAFKA CONNECTION INITIATING...");   
    Properties consumerProps = new Properties();
    consumerProps.put("exclude.internal.topics",  false);
    consumerProps.put("group.id" , "test");
    consumerProps.put("bootstrap.servers", servers);
    consumerProps.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");  
    consumerProps.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

    //ConsumerConfig consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig(consumerProps);
    //ConsumerConnector consumer = kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(
    //       consumerConfig);

    //Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    //topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(1));
    //Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
    //List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);

    KafkaConsumer<String, String> kconsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProps); 
    kconsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic)); 

    try {
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kconsumer.poll(10);

            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)

                System.out.println(record.offset() + ": " + record.value());
        }
    } finally {
          kconsumer.close();
    }
```

And the snapshot of what the message looks like below; at the bottom of the image:

[image: consumer offset]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's possible to directly read from the `__consumer_offsets` topic, this is not the recommended or easiest method.

If you can use the Kafka 2.0, the best is to use the AdminClient APIs to describe groups:

- [listConsumerGroupOffsets()](http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#listConsumerGroupOffsets-java.lang.String-org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.ListConsumerGroupOffsetsOptions-): to find all offsets for a specific group
- [describeConsumerGroups()](http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeConsumerGroups-java.util.Collection-): to find details about members of a group

---

In case, you absolutely want to read directly form `__consumer_offset`, you need to decode the record to make them human readable. This can be done using the  `GroupMetadataManager` class:

- [GroupMetadataManager.readMessageKey()](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/coordinator/group/GroupMetadataManager.scala#L1211) can be used to decode the message key and retrieve the topic-partition this entry refers to. This can return 2 types of objects, for consumer positions, you are only interested in `OffsetKey` objects.
- [GroupMetadataManager.readOffsetMessageValue()](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/coordinator/group/GroupMetadataManager.scala#L1240) can be used to decode message values (for keys that were `OffsetKey`) and find the offsets information.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52266219/1765189) from the question you linked contains skeleton code to perform all that.

Also note that you should not deserialize the records as string but instead keep them as raw bytes for these methods to be able to decode them correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have not yet worked this through but your detailed explanation is the best response I have got from anywhere. Appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was reopened. I had closed it as a duplicate after I wrote the answer you linked to. I can reference the AdminClient methods there, too