# What happens if offsets get corrupted in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

how can we handle offset corruption ?

I want to save the offset logs somewhere else or maybe take snapshots of the offsets. How can I do this ?

Comment: Is this a scenario you're actively experiencing? Specifically, what error are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka stores offsets in topic named _consumer_offsets. Consumers commit the offsets into this topic and the value of auto.offset.reset (earliest/latest/none) determines the strategy to start reading the messages from partition. offset log retention is specified by broker properties.

`auto.offset.reset = latest` => will start reading messages from last committed offset, if not found then it will wait for new messages to arrive and start from there. No exception thrown

`auto.offset.reset = earliest` => Again it will not throw any exception and it will start reading messages from the beginning if offsets exists.

`auto.offset.reset = none` => It will throw an exception, when offset are not found.

You can use assign and seek to fetch specific data

```
        //assign - set topic and partition you you want to read from using TopicPartion
        TopicPartition topicPartitionToReadFrom = new 
        TopicPartition(topic, 0);
        long offsetToReadFrom = 15L;
        consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(topicPartitionToReadFrom));
        
        //seek - set position of the consumer manually by calling
        //KafkaConsumer.seek(TopicPartition partition, long offset)
        consumer.seek(topicPartitionToReadFrom, offsetToReadFrom);
```

**To store the offset log** => _consumer_offsets is topic so you can [write a consumer for this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925866/kafka-how-to-read-from-consumer-offsets-topic) and store the messages into storage of your choice.

Comment: How does this answer relate to the question about corruption?